# Is my method correct to find Minimal Polynomial for a $5\times 5$ triangular matrix?

Tags: matrices, minimal-polynomials, block-matrices

I've been tasked with finding the minimal polynomial of the following matrix:
$$A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 &0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 &0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &0 & 1 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ]
$$
Since its triangular, its easy to see that: $p_A = x^3(x-1)^2$

Now, calculating the multiplication of this matrix by itself is a lot of work, and I was wondering if my way of addressing it is correct, and if not what will be the best way to do so.

What I tried doing is dividing the matrix into two blocks as such: $A =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    B & 0  \\
    0 & C  \\\end{matrix} \right ]$ where $B$ is $3\times 3$ and $C$ is $2\times 2$,
then finding the Minimal Polynomial for each. which is $x^3$ and and $(x-1)$.

Is that a correct way of doing it? finding the Minimal for each ? because individually, they become zero so does that means the other one can be 'smaller'?

Comment: The determinant of a block matrix like that one is $|B|\times|C|$

Comment: You don't actually write what you do with the minimal polynomials of the diagonal blocks, so it is hard for us to tell whether what you do is correct. But as a matter of principle, it is possible to determine the minimal polynomial of a _block diagonal_ matrix for the minimal polynomials of the diagonal blocks. (The same is not true for a block triangular matrix.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a diagonal block matrix $\begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & C\end{pmatrix}$.

Then for every polynomial $P$ we have $P(A) = \begin{pmatrix} P(B) & 0 \\ 0 & P(C)\end{pmatrix}$.

It follows $P(A) = I \iff P(B) = I$ and $P(C) = I \iff P$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $B$ and $P$ is a multiple of the minimal polynomial of $C \iff P$ is a multiple of the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials of $B$ and $C$.

Comment: So does that means my method is correct?

Comment: yup${}{}{}{}{}$